# Can a block of memory be partially freed?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, malloc, free

I'm writing a very memory intensive program that will have dozens of malloc'd arrays. When the app receives a low memory warning, I want to dump the lower half of each of these arrays. Is there any way to do this?

I need some way that I can preserve half of the memory in each array. Obviously, if the app has low memory, I can't allocate a smaller array, copy half of my data into it, and then free the old array. Is there any function that can free a block of memory starting at pointer A and ending at pointer B or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realloc() can return the trailing portion of the memory of a malloc back to the allocation pool, but can't return it to the OS.

Realloc() also won't help with memory fragmentation, which is likely a problem in a low-memory situation.

Comment: Use realloc().  It'll reduce the size of the block of memory you've allocated for you.  Don't worry about fragmentation; the operating system's memory allocator will take care of it.  If you were on a simpler OS it might be more of an issue, but iOS has a very advanced allocator.

Answer (score 0):

If they are NSMutableArrays, you can replace the objects in the lower end with a single instance of `[NSNull null]`, thereby releasing all of those objects.

[NSNull Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Filling in the array with `[NSNull null]` will not change the length of the array, creating a strange situation.  Better to call `[mutableArray removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(indexOfFirstObjectToRemove, [mutableArray count] - indexOfFirstObjectToRemove)]`.  That will release those objects and resize the array properly.

Comment: no, it won't free the array memory, but will free the objects, likely much larger footprint than the pointers to them.  yes, removing them is better!  i thought perhaps he wanted to maintain their indexes for some reason (don't know why i thought that - likely i was assuming he was using table view)

Comment: does mutable array recapture end space at any point?  i would assume not.

Comment: I'm not sure if it recaptures the space, since it's not indicated in the documentation.  If it does, it's an implementation detail and shouldn't be relied upon.